# RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey - Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, registry

I'm not sure why this is throwing an exception... The exception isn't very specific..  Am I missing something? :(

I'm essentially trying to update a registry value on a remote machine. On the `RegistryKey Key` line, an exception is thrown: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` This is because the `key` is getting set to `null`. However, if I shorten the `OpenSubKey` value to just `OpenSubKey("software",true);` it works just fine.  But I need to get two subkeys deeper than *Software*. Is there a limitation on the `OpenSubKey` class when it's used with the `OpenRemoteBaseKey` class?

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController();
        service.MachineName = store;
        try
        {
            //Enable Remote registry
            string commandStart = @"/k sc \\" + store + " config remoteregistry start= auto && exit";
            string commandStop = @"/k sc \\" + store + " config remoteregistry start= disabled && exit";
            Process.Start("cmd.exe", commandStart);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            service.ServiceName = "remoteregistry";
            service.Start();

            //Disable User Input
            RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, store).OpenSubKey(@"software\realvnc\vncserver",true);
            key.SetValue("DisableLocalInputs", "1");
            CheckIsDisabled(key);

            //Re-enable User Input
            key.SetValue("DisableLocalInputs", "0");
            service.Stop();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Process.Start("cmd.exe", commandStop);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Exception");
        }
```

Comment: OpenSubKey() returns null when it failed.  The NRE is the inevitable outcome when you don't use a debugger and don't check for it.  Exceptions are your friend, they tell you when you write bad code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Are their limitations to appending more than one subkey to the OpenSubkey(string) when using OpenRemoteBaseKey?  If I drop the string to just **.OpenSubKey(@"software",true);,  I'm returned with the correct results.